# How to add baseline shift(subscript, superscript) info for text for creating PDF using internal format structure?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

In one of the application they are creating PDF from SVG. To construct PDF they are constructing buffer as PDF internal structure tree( header, body,xref table,trailer etc). In SVG I have tspan element with baseline-shift attribute.
How to mention this baseline shift attribute and its value in PDF internal structure buffer?

For example to mention font details we are using /fontdescriptor in the PDF internal structure likewise how to mention baseline shift value for tspan in PDF intrenal struture?

Answer (score 0):

By using ts operator as mentioed in this link https://www.syncfusion.com/succinctly-free-ebooks/pdf/text-operators I am able to achive subscript and superscript text.